# Create hierarchy based on pre-defined levels in Excel (Formula or VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, formula, hierarchy

Below is my current Excel table:

[image]

I want to automatically generate the third column in yellow as a hierarchical view of all activities. I tried to solve this challenge with formulas but I am not sure that would be the best way to do it.

Has someone already faced and solved this requirement in Excel? Any advice/suggestions to guide me?

Many thanks and best regards!

Comment: It would be useful if you explained the logic that you want the hierarchy to follow.

Comment: I want the hierarchy to follow this logic: Level 1 then 1.X Level 2 then 1.1.X Level 3 then 1.1.1.X by keeping the whole hierarchy consistent.

Comment: The logic is still not completely defined. For example, consider the row 8 (`Activity 7`), how can one know that it should be `1.2` instead of, say, `1.1.1.5` ? Same goes for `Activity 15` on row 16...

Comment: The logic is based on the level so row 8, it should be 1.2 cause the level is 1 and row 16, it should be 1.2.2 cause the level is 2.Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste this macro in the *Worksheet's code Module* and run it from there:

```
Sub CalculateHierarchy()

    Dim rLevels As Range, rLevel As Range
    Dim level As Integer, maxLevels As Integer, cur As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim h As String, counts() As Integer

    Set rLevels = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    maxLevels = WorksheetFunction.Max(rLevels)
    ReDim counts(1 To maxLevels)

    cur = 1
    For Each rLevel In rLevels
        level = rLevel.Value
        If level > cur + 1 Then
            rLevel.Activate
            MsgBox "error at row " & rLevel.Row & " level increase by more than 1"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        h = ""
        counts(level) = counts(level) + 1
        For i = 1 To level
            h = h & "." & counts(i)
        Next
        h = Mid(h, 2)
        For i = level + 1 To UBound(counts)
            counts(i) = 0
        Next
        rLevel.Offset(, 2).Value = h
        cur = level
    Next
    rLevel.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot A.S.H. I will try this macro and give you a feedback shortly.

Comment: "Me.Activate: rLevel.Activate": I got the message "Invalid use of Me keyword". Do I need a specific add-on in Excel?

Comment: That's because you did not paste the code in the worksheet's code module as in my answer.

Comment: I removed this line and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot A.S.H. I know it was not my initial requirement but I noticed that having the "1." at the beginning of each label of the hierarchy is pointless. Do you have the same code to get 1-1.1-1.1.1. etc. Basically it's just removing the "1." begin of each result. PS: I already voted up on your answer ;)

Comment: No problem, see edit. But no you did note vote up the answer. You can't, you only can *"accept it"* with the `v` check on the top-left :)

Comment: @FlorianM. You're welcome. I added a little line to color the hierrachy column in Yellow. Forgot that :D